# Bootstrap 3 typeahead.js - remote url attributes

Tags: typeahead, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead.js

I'm trying to call my remote url with added attributes to the url.

For now I have this working:

```
$('#league').typeahead({
        remote: '/typeahead/get_league?query=%QUERY',
        limit: 10
});
```

Now I would like to do something like this:

```
$('#league').typeahead({
        remote: function () {
            var q = '/typeahead/get_league?query=%QUERY';
            if ($('#sport').val())
                q += "&sport=" + encodeURIComponent($('#sport').val());
            return base_url + q;
        },
        limit: 10
});
```

I would like to add the GET attribute 'sport' to the URL so I can narrow down my query on the backend. I tried the code above but I get a JS error.

The previous version of Bootstrap Typeahead allowed this type of setup. It was very useful as I could update the remote URL every time a key get hit.

Any idea how to make that work for this version ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`remote` is exclusively for [typeahead.js](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) (not part of Bootstrap). But you are not using the `remote` correctly, it can be either a **string** or an **object**, not a function.

When you need to change the request URL, you can use `replace`:

```
$('#league').typeahead({
    remote: {
        url: '/typeahead/get_league?query=%QUERY',
        replace: function () {
            var q = '/typeahead/get_league?query=%QUERY';
            if ($('#sport').val()) {
                q += "&sport=" + encodeURIComponent($('#sport').val());
            }
            return base_url + q;
        }
    },
    limit: 10
 });
```

Check the docs [here](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/#remote)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am using typeahead.js.
My problem comes from the fact that I can't use a function. Because I need to set my URL at the init, the #sport is not yet containing any value. That is why I would like to set it every time I hit a key and not ahead of time ...

I was able to do that using bootstrap 2.0 typeahead, now with typeahead.js I can't ... that's a big drawback. 

Any idea how I can work around that ?

Answer (score 5):

Hieu Nguyen solution will not work for %QUERY wildcards.
According to Bloodhound.js documentation,

replace – .... ***If set, no wildcard substitution will be performed on url.***

[Bloodhound docs on github](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md)

So %QUERY will be passed as string without being replaced by text entered from user.

So you should put typeahead value into your url :

```
$('#league').typeahead({
remote: {
    url: '/typeahead/get_league?query=%QUERY',
    replace: function () {
        var q = '/typeahead/get_league?query=' + $('#league').val();
        if ($('#sport').val()) {
            q += "&sport=" + encodeURIComponent($('#sport').val());
        }
        return base_url + q;
    }
},
limit: 10
```

});

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @fredtantini: I cannot add comment, so I have had to make a post. Surely you can close response on a "formalism" bases, but please next time take your time to understand the post and eventually report it's content as comment, because sometimes consideration from new users like me can save a lot of time to those who read the response marked as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete example with the QUERY result as well passed. Note that when the remote method is used variable substitution no longer functions. Thanks to [hieu-nguyen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2527433/hieu-nguyen) for the majority of it!

```
jQuery('#city').typeahead({
    name: "cities",
    remote: {
        url: current_web_root + '?action=ajax|getcities&query=%QUERY',
        replace: function () {
            var q = current_web_root + '?action=ajax|getcities&query=' + jQuery('#city').val();
            if (jQuery('#state').val()) {
                q += "&state=" + encodeURIComponent(jQuery('#state').val());
            }
            return q;
        }
    },      
    cache: false
}); 

jQuery("#state").change(function (e) {
    jQuery('#city').val("");
});
```