# Typeahead not working: not showing typeahead suggestions when I type

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, typeahead.js

I followed the [typeahead documentation example: The Basics](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/).  It worked when I copy/pasted the example code from 'The Basics'.  All I changed was I did an ajax request in place of that static array.

Code:

```
var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
    return function findMatches(q, cb) {
        var matches, substringRegex;
        matches = [];
        substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');
        $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
            if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                matches.push(str);
            }
        });
        cb(matches);
    };
};

/* only part I really changed */
/* I replaced the static array from the example */
/* with an array I am getting from ajax request. */
var agencies_ary = []
$.ajax({
    url: "agencies/get_unique_agency_names",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data){
        agencies_ary = data;
    }
})


$('.typeahead').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
    },
    {
        name: 'agencies_ary',
        source: substringMatcher(agencies_ary)
});
```

The ajax request works.  It properly returns an array of names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show two different solutions.  Both work.  One is a lot shorter than the other.

**Solution 1**:

```
var agency_names = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  prefetch: 'agencies/get_unique_agency_names'
});

$('.typeahead.name_input').typeahed(null, {
  name: 'agency_names',
  source: agency_names
});
```

**Solution 2**

The issue I had with the code in the original question was that the javascript was loading before the ajax request was sent.  To do the ajax request before the javascript, I simply had to specify the javascript within `.done`:

```
var agencies_ary = [];
$.ajax({
    url: "agencies/get_unique_agency_names",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data){
        agencies_ary = data;
        console.log(agencies_ary[0]);
    }
}).done(function(){

    var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
        return function findMatches(q, cb) {
            var matches, substringRegex;
            matches = [];
            substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');
            $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
                if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                    matches.push(str);
                }
            });
            cb(matches);
        };
    };


    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 1
        },
        {
            name: 'agencies_ary',
            source: substringMatcher(agencies_ary)
        });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution to wait for ajax call to finish and then setup typeahead is one way to do it and congrats on making it work :), but IMO it's simpler and faster to have typeahead make the call with something like:

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({ 
    remote: { url: "agencies/get_unique_agency_names" } 
 })
```

Have a look at [Bootstrap 3 typeahead.js - remote url attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18117476/bootstrap-3-typeahead-js-remote-url-attributes) for more suggestions.

Comment: I attempted replacing all the code I have in my answer below with your suggested answer above.  Unfortunately it was not working for me.