# how to pass two values in remote function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to pass more than one value to the `search.php` page how can i do that?

```html
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Ajax Search Box using PHP and MySQL</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="typeahead.min.js"></script>
    <script  >
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        name: 'typeahead',
        remote: 'search.php?key=%QUERY',
        
        prefetch: 'search.php',
        limit : 10
    });
});
    </script>
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
        <h1>Ajax Search Box using Node and MySQL</h1>
         <button type="button" >Visit Tutorial</button>
        <input type="text" name="typeahead" class="typeahead" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Type your Query">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use the &  to add more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 typeahead.js - remote url attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18117476/bootstrap-3-typeahead-js-remote-url-attributes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use & will not work with typeahead you need to use `replace` to process the query string before it is set.

```
$('#Last_Name').typeahead({
  name: 'typeahead',
  remote: {
    url: 'Search.pl?query=%QUERY',
    replace: function(url, uriEncodedQuery) {
      var QUERY2 = $("#textfield").val(); // get other field value
      if (!val) return url;
      return url + '&Key2=' + encodeURIComponent(QUERY2)
    },
   limit : 10
});
```

After Edit :

I have create A fiddle with two input box,one have typeahead and other input's value just passing with type head you will see it by net panel(firebug) or whether you  use to see ajax calls you can see

http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q=%QUERY&newField=10&callback=jQuery191022225840536777897_1447822862109&_=1447822862110

in which "newField" is the other input field

[**Here The Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CNMfL/130/)

Comment: can you please explain how will the value pass to that?

Comment: are you want value form a dom element ?

Comment: i am new to this so dont know much about it.i used this to pass first value.</style>
  </head>
  <body>
        <h1>Ajax Search Box using Node and MySQL</h1>
         <button type="button" >Visit Tutorial</button>
        <input type="text" name="typeahead" class="typeahead" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Type your Query">
  </body>
</html>

Comment: this isn't working for me.i have updated my code again.you can please check that as it's working absolutely fine for single value.

Comment: what is your other value ?

Comment: i want another text field.

Comment: yes let me know your other value first, (key and value you want to pass)

Comment: i need another textfield and as i enter anything in it it passes the value to search.php file along with the other key value.

Comment: i have updated my answer give id to that input field and use it

Comment: after using this the first field is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `&` for separation of variables.For your code do some thing like this.

```
$('input.typeahead').typeahead({
   name: 'typeahead',
   remote:'search.php?var1=value1&var2=value2',
   limit : 10
});
```

Comment: what does name:,remote:, mean here.like how do they work?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways. The first is create a FORM and send all the variables of the form, like this

```
url: 'Search.pl?' + $( "#myUrl" ).serialize(),
```

Another way is adding all the variables you need separated by a "&"

```
url: 'Search.pl?var1=' + value1 + '&var2=' + value2,
```